# Is there an isometry between $L^2([0,1])$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I was wondering whether there can exist an isometric operator from a bounded $L^2([0,1])$ space to one with an unbounded interval, let's say $L^2(\mathbb{R})$? Both shall be equipped with the standard Lebesgue measure and the Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/319724/, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/582867/

Comment: thanks. I see, pretty easy actually. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple change of variable will work. Find any smooth strictly increasing function $\rho$ that maps $\mathbb{R}$ onto $(0,1)$. Then $\rho' > 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and
$$
           \int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{2}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f\circ\rho(t)|^{2}\rho'(t)dt
$$
The map $f \in L^{2}(0,1) \mapsto \sqrt{\rho'}f\circ \rho$ is a unitary map from $L^{2}(-1,1)$ onto $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.